# django - two seperate iOS apps possible?

Tags: ios, swift, django

I have an iOS app using Django as my backend. I have two types of users, business and customer, that are both using one iOS application. On my log in page I use a toggle button that allows the user to choose whether they want to log in as a customer or a client.

Would it be possible to use two iOS apps, one for business and one for customers, instead of having them all in one application?

I only created one Django App, if I were to separate my business and customers to two iOS apps, would it cause me to have to create two separate Django Apps as well or could I continue with my current Django set up with one application?

Comment: Why would you give the user the option of choosing their login type? That's insane. The user should only enter their username and password and when the login confirmation is complete, you should be able to obtain user permissions from the server which tells you either the type of user (customer or business) or what permissions they have so your app knows what parts/features of the app the user has access to.

Comment: @rmaddy this is exactly what I needed! Simple, yet productive for what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to split them up, but it depends on what the differences are between the business and the customers app. If they both have a lot of components in common it'll save you a lot of time by just making a switch button and use 1 app. If they're totally different, go with two and you could still use the same Django App.

Comment: I'll add an "in-between". If there are major differences in UI (and of course, login logic) but not with the app logic, you can create two app along with a Framework for the common logic. This is strictly on the iOS side. How this equates to the Django side, well, truth is, **all** of this is landscape design and only the OP knows for sure what's best.